# How to select div in parent page from an iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I want to select a div which is in parent aspx page from a page which is called in an iframe. What i have tried is

`$(parent.document.getElementById('dvwdgloader2')).hide();`

but it only works in IE but not in other browser? how to solve this issue?

Furthermore iframe page is running on different port can this be the issue as firebug is showing

> Permission denied to access property '$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out that you cannot access parent page elements from an iframe page  if they are running on different domains. That's why firefox firebug is showing

> Permission denied to access property '$'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
parent.$('#dvwdgloader2').hide();
```

add "parent" keyword before your selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the proper way

```
$('#dvwdgloader2', window.parent.document).hide();
```

Comment: In firefox its still not working further in firebug it shows Permission denied to access property '$'

Answer (score 0):

try this..  `$('iframe', parent.document).parents().find('#dvwdgloader2')`

Answer (score 0):

```
The following code will help for u...
```

Javascript code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.opener.document.forms[0].length; i++) {
                        if (window.opener.document.forms[0][i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "DIV") {
                            if (window.opener.document.forms[0][i].name == "divname") {

                            }
                        }
                    }
```